# Como enviar um arreio de múltiplas colunas em um único botão com ng-repeat e angular

Tags: html, angularjs

Tenho um formulário em formato de *grid*, nele apresento as informações da tabela `Itens` do meu banco (74 ao total).
A intenção deste formulário *grid* é adicionar dois campos: **preço** e **preço bdi** em todos estes itens.

Meu problema é que não estou conseguindo enviar a informação dos 74 registros em um único botão.

Estou usando o `ng-repeat` na tabela para mostrar os 74 itens no meu formulário *grid*, e ainda neste `ng-repeat` tenho os inputs.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr id="fundocoreditarcd">
            <th>Código Tipo Item</th>
            <th>Código Item</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Preço</th>
            <th>Preço BDI</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in itens">
            <td>{{item.tipo_item_cod_tipo_item}}</td>
            <td>{{item.cod_item}}</td>
            <td>{{item.descricao}}</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.preco" class="money" id="preco" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.precoBdi" class="money" id="bdi" /></td>
            <td><a href="/cid/editarLote"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> <a href="http://geradormemes.com/media/created/8kbx7r.jpg" class=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a> </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <button ng-click="addPrecoItens(item)" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</table>
```

Parte do controller **JS**:

```
$http.get("read/itens")
.success(function (item) {
    $scope.itens = item;
    console.log($scope.itens);
})
.error(function (erro) {
    console.log(erro);
});

$scope.addPrecoItens = function (item) {
$scope.itensLote = item;
console.log($scope.itensLote);
/*$http.put('read/itens/', $scope.itensLote)
    .success(function () {
        console.log($scope.itensLote);
        $scope.mensagem = 'itens editados!';
    })
    .error(function (erro) {
        $scope.mensagem = 'Erro ao editar itens!';
        console.log(erro)
    });*/
};
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer fazer? Você quer mandar todos os 74 registros ao backend ao clicar no botão?

Comment: Vou receber um documento json de arrays com 74 itens, e usando o ng-repeat para exibir as informações na tabela. Quero enviar esses 74 itens com mais dois campus inputs ao clicar no botão para enviar para o servidor. Não estou conseguindo pegar os valores dos campos da tabela para enviar. No caso não sei como pegar os valores exibidos pelo ng-repeat para e enviá-los.

Comment: suponho que seu `$scope.item` tenha 74 itens... entao utilize o `$index`,  `ng-model="item[$index].precoBdi"` por exemplo, assim voce envia o model atualizado(`$scope.item)` para o servidor

Comment: Sim, os _74 itens_ estão dentro do `$scope.item`, contudo quando vamos enviar as informações pela função do botão 
`<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addPrecoItens(item)" value="enviar">`
O `$scope.item` está vazio, porque ele esta fora da tabela do `ng-repeat` , quando ele está dentro da tabela do `ng-repeat` o`$scope.item` está preenchido com os valores dos` 74 itens`, mas os botões se repetem para cada linha dos` 74 itens`

Obs.: Não funcionou usando o index da maneira que você falou, ao clicar no botão retorna na tela vazio.